# Remove HTML elements on twitch.tv isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

What's wrong with this code for my Chrome extension to remove Vod titles from twitch.tv?

*content.js*:

```js
var text = document.getElementsByTagName('video-preview-card__title video-preview-card__title--twoline overflow-hidden relative mg-t-05 font-size-5');
for (var i = 0, l = text.length; i < l; i++) {
  text[i] = text[i].style.display='none';
}
```

*manifest.json*:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Remove Twitch Vod Title HTML",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Removes Twitch Vod Title HTML",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://go.twitch.tv/*", "https://www.twitch.tv/*"]
  }]

}
```

Comment: twitch.tv is a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) so you need to use a MutationObserver or find out which page events it uses and listen to them, see this answer: [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your getElementsByTagName call looks wrong, you should pass a single tagName to it, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

If you are looking for a more complex selector, you should use querySelectorAll, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Moreover there is no need to do

```
text[i] = text[i].style.display='none';
```

It should be changed to just

```
text[i].style.display='none';
```

In addition to that, the DOM elements you are looking for might be created asynchronously after the DOM has loaded.

A **dirty but simple** solution is to wrap your code in a setInterval, to check every few seconds (or milliseconds).
Example, check every second:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var text = document.querySelectorAll(...);
  for (var i = 0, l = text.length; i < l; i++) {
    text[i].style.display='none';
  }
}, 1000);
```

This solution will also hide the elements again in case the page resets their display state for whatever reason.

You might want consider using the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for a more robust and performance aware solution.